# App Engine App failing with File(/base/data/home/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json) is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

My Google App Engine based website started failing suddenly with following error -

```
file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/base/data/home/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json) is not within the allowed path(s):
```

Any help/pointers will be appreciated as my website is currently down because of it.

Comment: Hi @amit.kumar checking for similar cases, it seems this might be related to updates done to the website, which causes App Engine to not update the path sometimes - as this similar case [here](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/php-warning-file_exists-open_basedir-restriction-in-effect/). Considering that, could you please give it a try in one of the solutions mentioned in the above link or in this other one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858986/symfony2-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect)?

Comment: Thanks @gso_gabriel for looking into it but it doesn't seem to be same problem as redeployment of code didn't work. Moreover i am not using wordpress or any other CMS framework. It is a plain PHP website

Comment: Hi @amit.kumar thanks for the confirmation. As a last shot, before contacting the [Google's 1:1 Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), maybe this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418798/google-cloud-api-application-default-credentials) might help. There is some solutions for errors related to the `application_default_credentials.json` file, which might help you. In case it doesn't I believe contacting Google's direct support is the best option, so they can access your instance and check what's it's not working properly.

Comment: I had posted it to Google Issue Tracker and it turned out that there was an issue from AppEngine side regarding resolving home directory for PHP 5.5 applications.

Once they had applied the fix, error changed to permission denied and then a redeployment of application without any changes made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I post here another possible solution as I had exaclty the same error message, even the reason was different. This is why this question came up while I searched for it.

*I am using the Google Translation API:*
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.153.0/translate/v2/translateclient

In my case I didn't provide in `$translate = new TranslateClient();` the parameter `key`.
Providing the Google API key `$translate = new TranslateClient([ "key" => "my-key" ]);` fixed it.